# list styling applying to nested list elements in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

when i apply width as 100% to list elements,the nested list elements will also get the same width! i dont want that to happen..how to make not applicable to listed elements.

for ex:html structure

```
<ul>
  <li>        
    <ul>   
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>            
  </li>
</ul>
```

css structure: ul li{width:100%;}

but this applies to nested elements also! i.e "ul li ul li" too gets the width as 100%..i dont want this to happen! any solution?

Comment: Why not `ul li{width:100%;}` and `ul li ul li{width: <other value> }`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `ul li` it targets all `li` elements which are child of `ul` so logically, all the `li` nested under `ul` gets affected. If you want to target only 1st level of `li` elements you can use

```
body > ul > li {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The above selector selects `li` element which is directly nested under `ul` which is further directly nested to `body`. This way it won't select the nested `ul` element as it is not a direct child of the `body` element.

Replace `body` if you have any parent wrapper with a `class` or an `id`. Make sure you just don't use `ul > li` because this way it will again select the nested `li` as well.

Comment: For me the body did not work I needed to use article > ul > li {

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `>` selector where `ul > li` means *select all li whose parent is ul*. You can further refine the parent-child relationship by indicating additional levels.

```css
ul > li {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

ul > ul > li {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

By the way, if you put a list (ul) in a list item (li), you may get bullet styles you don't want like this:

- A
- B
- - 1
  - 2